# How to set GoogleTest variables GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR and GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY to CMake on Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake, googletest

There is a project that was developed for linux environment. Now I am trying to build this on windows using CMake.

I keep trying to build the project and always get this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files(x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files(x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files(x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindGTest.cmake:204 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
C:/Users/awy9/git/cmake_modules/modules/SigeoGTest.cmake:21 (find_package)  
C:/Users/awy9/git/cmake_modules/modules/SigeoInit.cmake:29 (include)  
CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)
```

How can I set these variables to work on this project now on Windows?

Comment: This is standard CMake message, when requested package(GTest in your case) is not found. You should install GTest before configuring your project. Or, if you already have installed it into non-standard location, pass this location via `GTEST_ROOT` variable: `cmake -DGTEST_ROOT=<GTest-install-location> ... `. As alternative for the passing variable to cmake, you can set environment variable: `set GTEST_ROOT=<GTest-install-location>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your help! 
The problem with GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR was solved with your help, but I still get these errors:

`CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageH
andleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)`

Comment: If GTest is installed correctly(include files + libraries), these variables should be set by `find_package(GTest)` call. Check you GTest installation, and check whether it contains library files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

@Tsyvarev helped me solving the first problem and I quote him:

> This is standard CMake message, when requested package(GTest in your case) is not found. You should install GTest before configuring your project. Or, if you already have installed it into non-standard location, pass this location via GTEST_ROOT variable: cmake -DGTEST_ROOT= ...
>
> As alternative for the passing variable to cmake, you can set environment variable: set GTEST_ROOT=

This solved the problem with the value of **GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR**, but I still had these errors:

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageH andleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message): Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)

**SOLUTION**

I figured that on Windows environment some values are different from what the manuals say.

After compiling Gtest, I got two libs: gtest.lib and gtest_main.lib
Then, I set these filepath variables:

> GTEST_LIBRARY=C:\Users\awy9\Softwares\Gtest\gtest-1.7.0\Debug\gtest.lib
> GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY=C:\Users\awy9\Softwares\Gtest\gtest-1.7.0\Debug\gtest_main.lib

Now everything is working!

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Honestly It's not the best idea to set hardcoded variables like you've done with GTEST_LIBRARY and GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY.

I had the exact same problem. I was using gtest 1.7.0 on windows and getting the same error.
Turns out "GTest" should be "gtest" (not capitalized).

So the code in my CMakeLists.txt became:

`find_package(gtest REQUIRED)`

Note that I was using CMake 3.9

---

### EDIT

I would highly recommend following this guide now:

http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

It is by far the best method I have found to use unbuilt gtest and gmock in your cmake project.

Comment: It is a joke that the actual documentation says GTest (but gtest is the working way of doing this..)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a similar issue when building my project through GitHub Actions on Windows platform.

Even if I export the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to enable the `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` to properly find the framework library (Windows is a bit nasty BTW), it continues to fail with `Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)`. *Note that it correctly fetches the include directory.*

After digging a little bit deeper into the issue I realized that on Windows the command `cmake --build . --target install` without any `--config` options, builds the library in `Debug` configuration, contrary to Linux and macOS.

If you are then building your project in `Release`, e.g. `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release && cmake --build . --config Release --target install`, the `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` won't find any GTest library because it searches for the nonexistent `Release` build.

In this case a better solution is to install GTest in `Release` mode w.r.t. hardcoding the library paths to fetch the `Debug\` directory builds.

I attach also the GitHub Action steps which may be helpful for someone:

```
    steps:
    - name: Clone GTest
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}
      run: git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git

    - name: Create GTest Build Environment
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/googletest
      run: cmake -E make_directory build

    - name: Configure GTest CMake
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/googletest/build
      run: cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11

    - name: Install GTest
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/googletest/build
      run: cmake --build . --config $BUILD_TYPE --target install || sudo cmake --build . --config $BUILD_TYPE --target install

    - name: Export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH on Windows
      shell: bash
      if: runner.os == 'Windows'
      run: echo '::set-env name=CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH::C:/Program Files (x86)/googletest-distribution'

    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - ... your project build steps
```